# How to get Chart after editing in Chart Editor?

Tags: java, teechart

I am using TeeChart to build charts. I see a ChartEditor in the jar which gives the facility to make changes to a chart on the fly. I want to do the following to the modified chart. Please let me know if such things are possible.

1. Getting the chart from ChartEditor and replacing it with the old chart.
2. Getting all the settings that were applied. I will put them to a particular file and then while this chart will again be loaded it will read the file to make changes. Then Chart Editor might not be used.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

> Getting the chart from ChartEditor and replacing it with the old
>   chart.

I'm not sure about what you mean here. You can link a ChartEditor component to a specific chart, for example:

```
 ChartEditor.editChart(myChart.getChart());
```

If this is not what you were looking for, please provide more detailed information.

> Getting all the settings that were applied. I will put them to a
>   particular file and then while this chart will again be loaded it will
>   read the file to make changes. Then Chart Editor might not be used.

Yes, you can export chart settings to a native TeeChart template file (.tej for tha TeeChart Java version) and load it afterwards. You'll find more detailed information in *Tutorial 9. Exporting and Importing Charts*. Tutorials can be found at the *Docs* folder included with the TeeChart Java installation.